# Use jq to convert json array to jsonl format

Tags: json, elasticsearch, jq, jsonlines

I have json like this:

```
[ {"one": 1}, {"two": 2}]
```

and wish to convert it to this format:

```
{"one": 1}
{"two": 2}
```

to facilitate indexing it into ElasticSearch. (latter is called 'jsonl' format).  JQ is my tool of preference but I can't figure out how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 34):

The key is the -c command-line option, which produces JSONL:

```
jq -c '.[]' test_array.json
```

Answer (score -3):

figured this out:

```
cat test_array.json |jq '.[]'
```